# Unable to Access the Dynamic control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created Views for Multiview dynamically . In the view control I have a Gridview control which has a checkbox control. I have a button in the main aspx page on click of which it will check(if checked or not) for all the checkbox and fetch the corresponding row from the gridview. The view is for tabbed menu. In each tab the the gridview populates the data in the runtime. Have defined the dynamic control in Page_PreInit.
I'm not able to access the checkbox . How would I achieve this .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Control.FindControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)

Comment: I tried using FindControl but its not working.Say When I use .Findcontrol(chk1) it is not identifying chk1(which is the checkbox). Can you tell me where should I write the FindContol method. I need that in the event of button

Comment: do you have just one checkbox? or in every row? If one you should write checkbox's id

Comment: There are checkbox in every row and this checkbox has also been build dynamically in the ItemTemplate of the Template field.

Comment: Than you should call FindControl in every row, foreach(var r in rows) r.FindControl("checkBoxId"); Give id to every checkbox when generating

Answer (score 0):

A recursive FindControl might be more helpful if you do have the control's ID.

```
public static T FindControlRecursive<T>(this Control parentControl, string id) where T : Control
    {
        T ctrl = default(T);

        if ((parentControl is T) && (parentControl.ID == id))
            return (T)parentControl;

        foreach (Control c in parentControl.Controls)
        {
            ctrl = c.FindControlRecursive<T>(id);

            if (ctrl != null)
                break;
        }
        return ctrl;
    }
// and then: Page.FindControlRecursive<CheckBox>(idOfYourControl);
```